# Make span take width up to floating buttons

Tags: html, css

So in my layout i'll have a main searchbar along with two buttons.

Just below there are various entries. Which one has a clickable Title to show it's contents and open/close buttons.

[Here's a JSfiddle MVE (with only two entries.)](http://jsfiddle.net/HenriAugusto/2of0sp1y/47/)

Since the titles are clickable i want them to occupy all the remaining space up to the floating buttons.

[image: Current VS Desired behaviour]

I've tried adding two options to `.entry_title`:

```
.entry_title {
   display: inline;
   width: 100%;
}
```

But this way the title will actually occupy a whole line (thus moving the buttons to the next one). I've also tried all the other `display` options.

I've tried solutions to other answers ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244927/input-text-auto-width-filling-100-with-other-elements-floating), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575114/floating-div-spanning-parents-width)) but couldn't make them work in my setup.

Comment: Try: position: relative; and display: inline-block;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skip the floats and use flex box. Just add `display:flex;` to .entry-bar and `flex-grow:1;` to `.entry-title;`

```
.entry_bar {
  display:flex;
}

.entry_title {
    background-color: green;
    user-select: none;
    flex-grow:1;
}
```

Comment: Both this and @jpmarks answers are good. I'm accepting this one because in this scenario i think flex boxes seem simpler. But the other grid solution given is more scalable.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your .entry_bar css to this:

```
.entry_bar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr max-content max-content;
}
```

I hardly recommend looking into CSS grid. Here is a great guide by css-tricks [CSS
-Grid Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: Thanks for the guide. By the way did you meant "strongly recommend" instead of "hardly recommend"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex-box

```css
.entry_bar {
  display:flex;
}

.entry_title {
    flex: 1;
}
```